# Setting Android WebView platform parameters or flags to Mobile

Tags: android, webview, parameters, android-webview, settings

I am running a WebView in an Android app and need to force either the platform parameters or flags or whatever to be "Mobile" instead of the default "Web". In other words I need the requests (calls) made by the WebView to indicate the platform is for "mobile" or "in-app" and not a "Web" request.

I've found no documentation on how to do this or anything like it. The Android Developer documentation does not offer enough under-the-hood info on how to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom webview client and trace all the urls.

```
WebViewClient myclient = new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // Trace the Url here
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // Trace the Url here
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            // Trace the Url here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            // Trace the Url here
        }
    };
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(myclient);
```

Vote Up if this helps.